# What would cause a well pump to suddenly be louder when operating?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump, well

We currently have an unknown (in terms of GPM) 3/4HP Franklin well pump, at an unknown depth (though our neighbor's well is at roughly 100').  Since we moved in, when the well pump is running, there has been a low, barely audible humming that can heard throughout the house.  About a year ago, our (ancient) pressure tank developed a leak, and so I replaced it with a larger, bladder style tank.  It takes a few minutes to fill, and quite a lot of water use to go below the switches 40psi for the well pump to kick in.

Yesterday, the well pump started making a louder, more high pitched hum.  It can be heard clearly outside at the well head.  The pump is performing the same as it was before (fully pressurizes the tank in about the same amount of time), just with this louder operating sound.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this or how to troubleshoot it before a very expensive well service call?

Comment: worn bearings is my first thought

Comment: There could be air in the system or some garbage in the pump. It is not often... but it is time to take it out and inspect it. replace and clean any thing that can be serviced. Roll the pipes and cable up neatly when pulling it out and always have one or two people to assist during all this.

Comment: If you can sound the well's water level, maybe that has changed?

Comment: Turns out the pump was shot.  37 year old pump..  And the reason it died?  Well screen was all plugged up, and the pump was pumping dry.  Lots of $$ later, and I have a new well pump, and a new well screen.  Was definitely out of the DIY range.

Comment: @MarkD you should put the reason in the answers and mark it as such so this will be noted as a closed question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the pump was shot. 37 year old pump.. And the reason it died? Well screen was all plugged up, and the pump was pumping dry. Lots of $$ later, and I have a new well pump, and a new well screen. Was definitely out of the DIY range.